# Can't draw "\mathds{C}" with manim on Google Colab

Tags: python, manim

I followed [the official manual for google colab](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/jupyter.html#google-colaboratory) and I'm trying to draw "\mathds{C}" with manim on Google Colab by below code.

```py
%%manim -qm -v WARNING Main

class Main(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex = Tex("$\\mathds{C}$")
        self.play(Create(tex))
```

This code shows below error.

```
[09/06/23 02:51:19] ERROR    LaTeX compilation error: Undefined control sequence.           tex_file_writing.py:285
                                                                                                                   

ERROR:manim:LaTeX compilation error: Undefined control sequence.

                    ERROR    Context of error:                                              tex_file_writing.py:319
                             \begin{document}                                                                      
                                                                                                                   
                             -> \begin{center}                                                                     
                             $\mathds{C}$                                                                          
                             \end{center}                                                                          
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   

ERROR:manim:Context of error: 
\begin{document}

-> \begin{center}
$\mathds{C}$
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that using `tex_template`

```py
%%manim -qm -v WARNING Main
template = TexTemplate(preamble="\\usepackage{dsfont}")
class Main(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex = Tex("$\\mathds{C}$", tex_template=template)
        self.play(Create(tex))
```